# strange behaviour of ternary operator in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

There is a properly working code:

```
#include <iostream>

int sum_odd_digits(int n)
{
  if(n==0) return 0;
  else return (((n%2)!=0)?n%10:0) + sum_odd_digits(n/10);
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  std::cout<<sum_odd_digits(25897641)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

But if to remove the outer parenthesis, i. e. replace

```
else return (((n%2)!=0)?n%10:0) + sum_odd_digits(n/10);
```

with

```
else return ((n%2)!=0)?n%10:0 + sum_odd_digits(n/10);
```

the program begins giving a wrong output result, i. e. begins working incorrectly.

Why? What is the difference between these 2 lines?

Comment: Try using more spaces and you might be able to read your code.

Comment: *Why? What is the difference between these 2 lines?* -- One line has outer parentheses while the other doesn't.  If parens make a difference, then its time to look at operator precedence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence): `+` has higher precedence than `?:`, so your incorrect version resolves to:

```
((n%2)!=0) ? n%10 : (0 + sum_odd_digits(n/10));
                    ^                        ^
                  // addition is grouped first
```

which now has obviously different grouping than the first version.

Comment: So, the outer parenthesis are necessary here for the compiler to parse the code correctly, aren't they?

Comment: Yes, although the inner ones in the boolean condition before `?` are not. i.e. you can write `(n%2 != 0 ? n%10 : 0)`

Comment: @And -- the compiler will parse the code _correctly_ with or without the parentheses. The outer parentheses are needed if the code without them doesn't say what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

That's an associativity problem case, due to [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), your compiler will understand :

```
variable = Expression1 ? Expression2 : Expression3; //General Ternary Syntax
```

Where : `0 + sum_odd_digits(n/10) = Expression 3.`